# How to register a service having multiple interfaces and use that service as a single instance in ConfigureServices .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have service which implements multiple Interfaces; for example

```
ServiceClass : IService1, IService2
{
// implementation
}
```

Now I need to register this service in ConfigureServices() in such a way that I have a single instance of SerivceClass and this instance can be used even if the IService1 or IService2 is injected via constructor. For ex,

```
public class SomeClass1: ISomeClass1
    {
      SomeClass1(IService1 service)
          {
           ...
          }
    }

public class SomeClass2 : SomeClass2
    {
      SomeClass2(IService2 service)
          {
           ...
          }
    }
```

I have tried registering the ServiceClass using its both Interfaces in ConfigureServices() but it would create multiple instances.

```
ConfigureServices(){

...
services.AddSingleton<IService1, ServiceClass>();
services.AddSingleton<IService2, ServiceClass>();
services.AddSingleton<ISomeClass1>(
                x => new SomeClass1(
                    x.GetRequiredService<IService1>(),
                    ));

services.AddSingleton<ISomeClass2>(
                x => new SomeClass2(
                    x.GetRequiredService<IService2>(),
                    )); 
....
}
```

I need to find a solution where I can inject the same instance to SomeClass1 and SomeClass2 eventhough the injected interfaces are different.

Comment: If your `ServiceClass` does not have any dependency then you can manually create it. Then you can use that [overload of the `AddSingleton`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addsingleton?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-servicecollectionserviceextensions-addsingleton-1(microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-iservicecollection-0)) which receives a concrete implementation, like `services.AddSingleton<IService1>(svcClassInstance);`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way to solve this is to register the implementing class, and then explicitly resolve the multiple interfaces from that:

```
services.AddSingleton<ServiceClass>();
services.AddSingleton<IService1, ServiceClass>(x => x.GetRequiredService<ServiceClass>());
services.AddSingleton<IService2, ServiceClass>(x => x.GetRequiredService<ServiceClass>());
```

There's an example of this approach [used here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/5a12420546d7f0d963bcccf082400c1b057e38ef/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DependencyInjection/HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L37-L39) for HttpClientFactory for example.